# Not routing to expected controller action, Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Rails 6
```

In my config/routes.rb, I have:

```
match "customers/current_customers" => "customers#current_customers", as: :current_customers, via: [:get]
```

And in my dropdown menu, I have:

```
.dropdown-menu aria-labelledby="Customers"
  button.dropdown-item type="button"
    = link_to current_customers_path
      = t('current_customers')
```

My routes, show:

```
customers GET /customers(.:format) customers#index 
POST /customers(.:format) customers#create 
new_customer GET  /customers/new(.:format) customers#new 
edit_customer GET  /customers/:id/edit(.:format)   customers#edit 
customer GET  /customers/:id(.:format) customers#show 
PATCH  /customers/:id(.:format) customers#update 
PUT  /customers/:id(.:format) customers#update 
DELETE /customers/:id(.:format) customers#destroy 
current_customers GET  /customers/current_customers(.:format)   customers#current_customers
```

And. in controllers/customers_controller.rb, I have:

```
def current_customers
  @customers = Customer.current_customers
end
```

When I select the menu item, the development log tells me:

```
Started GET "/customers/current_customers" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-03-13 18:04:15 -0700
Processing by CustomersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"assigned_customers"}
```

Which fails, obviously, with the following message:

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Customer with 'id'=current_customers):  
app/controllers/customers_controller.rb:86:in `set_customer'
```

Why is it going to the ***show*** action, instead of the current_customers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your routes get processed from the top-down, and priority is given to those at the top.

Assuming you also have a `resources :customers`, and then below this is the `match ...`, prioritizing the `match` should get you the result you're looking for. Additionally, using `collection`:

```
match "customers/current_customers" => "customers#current_customers", as: :current_customers, via: [:get]
resources :customers
```

or (preferred)

```
resources :customers do 
  collection do 
    get :current_customers
  end 
end
```

Comment: Yes, thank you, I forgot about the top to bottom rule. I prefer the collection: it seems like a more elegant solution